# Parse JSON file using GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I want to parse this **JSON** file in **JAVA** using **GSON** :

```
{
    "descriptor" : {
        "app1" : {
            "name" : "mehdi",
            "age" : 21,
            "messages": ["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
        },
        "app2" : {
            "name" : "mkyong",
            "age" : 29,
            "messages": ["msg 11","msg 22","msg 33"]
        },
        "app3" : {
            "name" : "amine",
            "age" : 23,
            "messages": ["msg 111","msg 222","msg 333"]
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to acceed to the root element which is : **descriptor**, after that the **app3** element and finally the **name** element.

I followed this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/, but it doesn't show the case of having a root and childs elements.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Imo, the best way to parse your JSON response with GSON would be creating classes that "match" your response and then use [`Gson.fromJson()`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) method.
For example:

```
class Response {
    Map<String, App> descriptor;
    // standard getters & setters...
}

class App {
  String name;
  int age;
  String[] messages;
  // standard getters & setters...
}
```

Then just use:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(yourJson, Response.class);
```

Where `yourJson` can be a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), any [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html), a [`JsonReader`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) or a [`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html).

Finally, if you want to access any particular field, you just have to do:

```
String name = response.getDescriptor().get("app3").getName();
```

You can always parse the JSON manually as suggested in other answers, but personally I think this approach is clearer, more maintainable in long term and it fits better with the whole idea of JSON.

Comment: I believe this captures the spirit of JSON much better than a "manual parser" approach

Comment: Thank you, but the JSON file will not contain only app1, app2, app3, it will be dynamic, so I will not be able to fix the class attributes..

Comment: @Mehdi see edited code, which is even simpler and allows you to have an arbitrary number of *app* objects in your JSON response, just changing the tipe for a `Map`... Btw, if you'll have an arbitrary number of app objects, you should say it in your original post! ;)

Comment: @MikO : Thank you, I did as you said, I changed the whole project and created classes but I get a nullPointerException, can you please check my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416965/nullpointerexception-json-parsing-in-java-using-gson
Thnk you :)

Comment: I'm having trouble grokking this; what should the getters and setters in the code above look like?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, just standard getters and setters! For example: `public String getName() { return this.name; }` and `public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }`

Comment: To read from file, you don't need `BufferedReader`: `gson.fromJson(new FileReader(filename), Response.class)` simply works!

Comment: so show an example with `JsonReader` since he literally said he wants to parse a **file**

Comment: @KrustytheClown as I said, `yourJson` variable in my example can be a `JsonReader` (among other things), so that is _literally_ an example using it! How to actually read a file contents into the `JsonReader` is another question. For that, just use `yourJson = new JsonReader(new FileReader("yourFile.json"))` for example. Actually you have that code in another answer!

Answer (score 20):

I'm using gson 2.2.3

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("jsonFile.json"));

    jsonReader.beginObject();

    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

    String name = jsonReader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("descriptor")) {
             readApp(jsonReader);

        }
    }

   jsonReader.endObject();
   jsonReader.close();

}

public static void readApp(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException{
    jsonReader.beginObject();
     while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
         String name = jsonReader.nextName();
         System.out.println(name);
         if (name.contains("app")){
             jsonReader.beginObject();
             while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                 String n = jsonReader.nextName();
                 if (n.equals("name")){
                     System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
                 }
                 if (n.equals("age")){
                     System.out.println(jsonReader.nextInt());
                 }
                 if (n.equals("messages")){
                     jsonReader.beginArray();
                     while  (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                          System.out.println(jsonReader.nextString());
                     }
                     jsonReader.endArray();
                 }
             }
             jsonReader.endObject();
         }

     }
     jsonReader.endObject();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) but why do we have to set `jsonReader.beginObject();` and `jsonReader.endObject();` in each method ? (main and readApp) Thank you :)

Comment: I agree with miko. GSON is a very powerful library for convert JSON-Java Object and viceversa.. I have used it that way in most projects.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that to be remembered while solving such problems is that in JSON file, a `{` indicates a `JSONObject` and a `[` indicates `JSONArray`. If one could manage them properly, it would be very easy to accomplish the task of parsing the JSON file. The above code was really very helpful for me and I hope this content adds some meaning to the above code.

The [Gson JsonReader documentation](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) explains how to handle parsing of `JsonObjects` and `JsonArrays`:

> - Within array handling methods, first call beginArray() to consume the array's opening bracket. Then create a while loop that accumulates values, terminating when hasNext() is false. Finally, read the array's closing bracket by calling endArray().
> - Within object handling methods, first call beginObject() to consume the object's opening brace. Then create a while loop that assigns values to local variables based on their name. This loop should terminate when hasNext() is false. Finally, read the object's closing brace by calling endObject().