# parse json object using gson in android

Tags: java, android, gson

i have an json object like this and i am getting this response in my Fragment.

json

```
{
   "data":{
      "categories":[
         {
            "id":"d5c4eedf-093e-422f-8335-6c6376ca3ccb",
            "schedule_m_id":1,
            "title_en":"Bakery Products",
            "title_fr":"Produits de boulangerie",
            "subtitle_en":"Bread, Cakes, Cookies, Crackers, Pies",
            "subtitle_fr":"Pain, gateaux, biscuits, craquelins, tartes",
            "created_at":"2015-03-04 15:39:44",
            "updated_at":"2015-03-04 15:39:44"
         },
         {
            "id":"6d1d4945-9910-40ae-82a8-3fe4137c24c2",
            "schedule_m_id":2,
            "title_en":"Beverages",
            "title_fr":"Boissons",
            "subtitle_en":"Soft Drinks, Coffee, Tea, Cocoa",
            "subtitle_fr":"Boissons gazeuses, café, thé, cacao",
            "created_at":"2015-03-04 15:39:44",
            "updated_at":"2015-03-04 15:39:44"
         }
      ]
   },
   "result":"success"
}
```

and my categories class is like this:

```
public class Categories {
    private int id;
    private String title_en;
    private String title_fr;
    private int schedule_m_id;
    private String subtitle_en;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle_en() {
        return title_en;
    }

    public void setTitle_en(String title_en) {
        this.title_en = title_en;
    }

    public String getTitle_fr() {
        return title_fr;
    }

    public void setTitle_fr(String title_fr) {
        this.title_fr = title_fr;
    }

    public int getSchedule_m_id() {
        return schedule_m_id;
    }

    public void setSchedule_m_id(int schedule_m_id) {
        this.schedule_m_id = schedule_m_id;
    }

    public String getSubtitle_en() {
        return subtitle_en;
    }

    public void setSubtitle_en(String subtitle_en) {
        this.subtitle_en = subtitle_en;
    }

}
```

In my fragment how can i parse this json object. i need to make an ArrayList which type is "Categories". i need this Categories object List to make an custom adapter. Can anybode help me.

```java
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response;
JSONObject dataProject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray products = dataProject.getJSONArray("categories");
Gson gson = new Gson();
Categories categories = new Categories();
ArrayList<Categories> items = new ArrayList<Categories>();
int productCount = products.length();

for (int i = 0; i < productCount; i++) {
    categories = gson.fromJson(products.get(i), Categories.class);
    items.add(categories);
}
```

```

Comment: sorry that was an error. nw look into it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416965/nullpointerexception-json-parsing-in-java-using-gson

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet What makes you think the OP is getting a NPE?

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that you've defined the `id` field in `Categories` as an `int`, but the json you're getting has some sort of GUID. `d5c4eedf-093e-422f-8335-6c6376ca3ccb` is **not** going to parse cleanly into an `int` field.

Comment: When I try to run a cut-down version of your code, I'm getting a `NumberFormatException` when gson tries to parse that field.

Comment: If I change the type of `id` to `String` in the `Categories` class, I can create a `JSONObject` using the sample json you provided and your code runs cleanly for me.  Try changing the type and let me know if your program is still failing.

Comment: @azurefrog The parsing is well explained there with similar json complexity.  This can easily be solved by simply creating a `Data` class that contains a `private Categories[ ] categoryArray`.

Comment: And then calling `gson.fromGson(response, Data.class)`

Comment: @azurefrog thanks for your comment. i have change the type of id. but problem with this line  `categories = gson.fromJson(products.get(i), Categories.class);` it's showing that it can not resolve method formjson.

Comment: Thanks @azurefrog i have solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I posting a class working with gson volley May be Helpful for you....

Step1. For Parsing your json data use "www.jsonschema2pojo.org/" and generate pojo classes. copy classes in your project with same name.

Step2. Just create a GsonRequest Class as follows (taken from  https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Listener<T> listener;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 * @param headers Map of request headers
 */
public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
        Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(
                response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
     } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

Step3.Now in your main Activity just use this "GsonRequest" class like that:

```
 mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    GsonRequest<MyPojoClass> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<MyPojoClass>(
            Request.Method.GET,
            apiurl,
            MyPojoClass.class,
            mySuccessListener(),
            myErrorListener());

     //Add below these code lines for "Retry" data fetching from api

    gsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    mRequestQueue.add(gsonRequest);
}

private Response.Listener<MyPojoClass> mySuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<CustomRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(MyPojoClass pRequest) {
            //do something
        }
    };
}

private Response.ErrorListener myErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println(volleyError.getMessage().toString());
        }
    };
}
```