# Android Json passing issue

Tags: android, json

I need to access json data from my android app. for that i have developed code. now i have small issue. but i can not solved it. it gives me a error like in image:

[image]

and print my json data and it likes this.

[image]

and this is my code.

```
String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);                
String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);  
String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
```

can someone please help me.

Comment: i believe you have to see my answer here to know more about `json` and how to parse it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746800/android-parse-jsonobject/19747171#19747171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you forgot to get json object first

```
JSONObject o = c.getJSONObject("yammer");

String date = o.getString(TAG_DATE);
String description = o.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
String title = o.getString(TAG_TITLE);
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks. i don't know how do i missed it. anyway thaks very much

Answer (score 1):

```
{ // json object node 
    "yammer": { // json object yammer
        "date": "2012-02-03", // string
        "description": "Lazdsasd",
        "title": "xzx"
    }
}
```

To parse

```
 try
 {
   JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("your json string");
   String yammer = jb.getString("yammer");
   JSONObject jb1 = new JSONObject(yammer);    
   String date = jb1.getString("date");
   Log.i("date","............"+date);
   String description = jb1.getString("description");
   String title = jb1.getString("title");
 }catch(Exception e)
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```