# How parse JSON array with multiple objects by JSON in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

How parse multiple objects `JSON`? Please help me.

My JSON,

```
{
    "result": [
        [{
            "date": "21.12.2016",
            "day": "\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430",
            "time": "08:00-09:20",
            "subject": "\u0424\u0456\u0437\u0438\u0447\u043d\u0430 \u0440\u0435\u0430\u0431\u0456\u043b\u0456\u0442\u0430\u0446\u0456\u044f (\u041f\u0440\u0421)",
            "room": "\u0430\u0443\u0434.309\/4 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043f\u0443\u0441 \u0432\u0438\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447 \u041a\u0430\u0440\u043f\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e \u042e.\u041c."
        }, {
            "date": "21.12.2016",
            "day": "\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430",
            "time": "09:30-10:50",
            "subject": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0456\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0456\u044f (\u041f\u0440\u0421)",
            "room": "\u0430\u0443\u0434.408\/4 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043f\u0443\u0441 \u0434\u043e\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442 \u0412\u0435\u0434\u043c\u0435\u0434\u0454\u0432 \u041c.\u041c."
        }, {
            "date": "21.12.2016",
            "day": "\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430",
            "time": "11:00-12:20",
            "subject": "(\u043f\u0456\u0434\u0433\u0440. 2) \u0413\u0456\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0442\u0430 \u043c\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0457\u0457 \u0432\u0438\u043a\u043b\u0430 (\u041f\u0440\u0421)",
            "room": "\u0430\u0443\u0434.\u0413\u0456\u043c\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u043d\u0438\u0439 \u0437\u0430\u043b\/\u0421\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441 \u0441\u0442. \u0432\u0438\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447 \u0411\u0430\u043b\u0430\u0448\u043e\u0432 \u0414.\u0406."
        }]
    ]
}
```

Comment: [look this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746800/android-parse-jsonobject)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746800/android-parse-jsonobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(responseString);
JsonArray result = obj.getJsonArray("result");

  for(int i = 0 ; i < result.length() ; i++){

       JsonArray dataArray = result.getJsonArray(i);
       for(int j = 0 ; j < dataArray.length() ; j++){

          String date = dataObj.optString("date");
          ...

       }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper** Use this library for mapping. And convert your pojo into desirable class using this :
**http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/** 
For details: **http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes**

Like :

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "result"
})
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("result")
    private List<List<Result>> result = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("result")
    public List<List<Result>> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @JsonProperty("result")
    public void setResult(List<List<Result>> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Then another java class will be

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "date",
    "day",
    "time",
    "subject",
    "room"
})
public class Result {

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty("day")
    private String day;
    @JsonProperty("time")
    private String time;
    @JsonProperty("subject")
    private String subject;
    @JsonProperty("room")
    private String room;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @JsonProperty("day")
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    @JsonProperty("day")
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    @JsonProperty("time")
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @JsonProperty("time")
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @JsonProperty("subject")
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    @JsonProperty("subject")
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @JsonProperty("room")
    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    @JsonProperty("room")
    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```