# GSON read into array class element

Tags: java, gson, topojson

I want to read `topojson` objects into a Java class. Topojson is a special class of JSON, defined where the objects have arcs in a lookup table as follows:

```
{
  "type":"Topology",
  "objects":{
    "collection":{
      "type":"GeometryCollection",
      "geometries":[
        {"type":"LineString","properties":{"id":842296681,"start":892624561,"end":892624564,"class":5,"lanes":null,"direction":"B","length":0.000485},"arcs":[0]},
        {"type":"LineString","properties":{"id":842296682,"start":892624563,"end":892624564,"class":5,"lanes":null,"direction":"B","length":0.000351},"arcs":[1]},
      ]
    }
  },
  "arcs":[
    [[4816,1007],[262,2281],[183,738]],
    [[4397,3892],[341,-268],[235,0],[288,402]]
  ],
  "transform":{
    "scale":[3.8203658765624953e-7,1.4901510251040002e-7],
    "translate":[-87.63437999816,41.86725999012999]},
    "bbox":[-87.63437999816,41.86725999012999,-87.63056001432003,41.86874999213999]
}
```

I am trying to do as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16378782/843419) and read the objects directly into a class, which I've sort of awkwardly defined as

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by gregmacfarlane on 7/11/17.
 */
public class TopoJsonNetwork {
  String type;
  Map<String, GeometryCollection> objects;
  ArrayList<Double[][]> arcs;
  Transform transform;

}

class GeometryCollection{
  String type;
  Geometry[] geometries;

}

class Geometry{

  String type;
  Map<String, String> properties;
  Integer[] arcs; // lines will have only a single arc


}


class Transform{
  Double[] scale;
  Double[] translate;
  Double[] bbox;

}
```

Everything works great when I call the gson reader

```
reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(topoFile));

Gson gson = new Gson();
TopoJsonNetwork topoNet = gson.fromJson(reader, TopoJsonNetwork.class);
```

meaning that all the objects of my class are populated --- except for the `arcs` array. The element is there, but with a `null` value. What should I change about how this element is defined so that it populates correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code I am able to get the expected results. I modified your main program and looped through the ArrayList as a 2D array using nested for loops. The result was a list of all the numbers from the `arcs` list in your class.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("topojson.json"));
Gson gson = new Gson();
TopoJsonNetwork topoNet = gson.fromJson(reader, TopoJsonNetwork.class);

for (Double[][] d : topoNet.arcs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(d[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, `topoNet.arcs` is a list of size 2, and as you might expect it contains a couple of two-dimensional `Double` arrays.

Comment: Hmmm. I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the `d : topoNet.arcs` call, both in my full program and in this MWE. Could it be a Java version thing?

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and Gson 2.6.2. Here's a direct link to download the project as I've got it currently running in my workspace. You should be able to simply import it and see how it goes on your end: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_iQPwucAbKASEowWkx3TTBUN00/view?usp=sharing . Click the download icon top-right to get the ZIP file.

Comment: Ha. Turns out I was reading from a debuggin json where I had taken out the arcs element. **facepalm**